# Allow access to single API without Authorization?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm sure I'm probably missing something fairly basic, but is there a way to expose `ApiController` to be accessed without Authorization? Removing `[Authorize]` or adding `[AllowAnonymous]` doesn't seem to help.

```
namespace Backend.Controllers
{
    [MobileAppController, Authorize]
    public class RebuildLocalDatabaseCheckController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("api/LastLocalDatabaseRebuildRequest")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JToken Get()
        {
            return JToken.FromObject(DateTimeOffset.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

This is for an Azure Mobile App that I've setup for a UWP app. I do want everything else to require authorization, and that part is working fine. I just want to expose this part without needing login from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code on my local side and it could work as expected.

[image]
[image]

For anonymous access, you need to remove the `Authorize` from your `RebuildLocalDatabaseCheckController` class for all actions or specify the `AllowAnonymous` for your specified action. For more details about custom API in azure mobile apps project, you could refer to adrian hall's book [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/#creating-a-basic-custom-api).

Additionally, if you app has been deployed to azure mobile app, for allowing anonymous against your custom API, you need to disable **App Service Authentication** or enable it with **Allow Anonymous requests (no action)** as follows:

[image]

Additionally, here is a blog about [Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/), you could refer to it for better understanding of app service authentication / authorization.